# Unusual crash with cocoa webView -elementAtPoint: (OS X)

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, webview

I have a subclass of `webView` that overrides `- hitTest:` The basic idea is that I want clicks on the webView to pass through to the nextResponder if the click was on the body DOM element. The method looks like this

```
- (NSView *)hitTest:(NSPoint)aPoint
{
    NSDictionary *dict = [self elementAtPoint:aPoint];
    if([[dict valueForKey:@"WebElementDOMNode"] isKindOfClass:[DOMHTMLBodyElement class]])
    {
        return (NSView *)[self nextResponder];
    }

    return [super hitTest:aPoint];
}
```

When run, it crashes on `elementAtPoint` with `EXC_BAD_ACCESS code=2`

Now, it gets weirder. If I breakpoint the app at that line, and do a `po [self elementAtPoint:aPoint]` in LLDB, LLDB just hangs until I do a ^C.

Weirder yet. If I comment out everything but the last return, break on the return statement, and run `po [self elementAtPoint:aPoint]` in LLDB—I get exactly what I expect, a nice dictionary telling me all about the DOM at that point.

What could be causing this behavior?

Note: This is on OS X, not iOS.

Answer (score 0):

> What could be causing this behavior?

Just look at `[WebView _elementAtWindowPoint:]` and `[WebView _frameViewAtWindowPoint:]` implementations in the [WebKit source code](http://www.opensource.apple.com/source/WebKit/WebKit-7533.18.1/mac/WebView/WebView.mm). Unfortunately, they use `hitTest:` to determine `elementAtPoint:`.

In my case, this workaround seems to work:

```cpp
- (NSView *)hitTest:(NSPoint)point
{
    if (m_hitTestEnabled)
    {
        [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:0.
                                         target:self
                                       selector:@selector(hitTestDelayed:)
                                       userInfo:@[ @(point.x), @(point.y) ]
                                        repeats:NO];
    }
    return [super hitTest:point];
}

- (void)hitTestDelayed:(NSTimer *)timer
{
    NSPoint point = NSMakePoint([[timer userInfo][0] floatValue], [[timer userInfo][1] floatValue]);

    m_hitTestEnabled = false;
    NSDictionary *dict = [self elementAtPoint:point];
    m_hitTestEnabled = true;

    if ([[dict valueForKey:@"WebElementDOMNode"] isKindOfClass:[DOMHTMLDivElement class]])
    {
        NSLog(@"divAtPoint: %@", dict);
    }
}
```

`m_hitTestEnabled` is set to `YES` in the `initWith...` method.

Why with a timer? Such operations on WebView are allowed only in main thread. So, we cannot launch another thread to get `elementAtPoint:` and wait for its completion in the "main" `hitTest:`. Maybe someone will come up with a better solution.